# How to clear chat NODE JS telegram bot (node-telegram-bot-api.)

Tags: node.js, node-telegram-bot-api

Hi guys i'm junior nodejs developper!

my question: How to clear chat on write text == cls

my code

```
const { chat, message_id } = message
const chatId = message.chat.id
const name = message.from.first_name
const text = message.text
// ================== on write "cls" clear chat
else if (text == 'cls') {
    bot.deleteMessage(chatId, chat.id)
    var msg = message;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think currently there isn't any method to clear whole chat using bot but
you can use simple loop to delete last 100 messages(only work for group chats and bot should have admin permission to delete messages). Like this,

```
const Telegram = require('node-telegram-bot-api')
const TOKEN = process.env.TOKEN || "<YOUR BOT TOKEN>";
const bot = new Telegram(TOKEN,{polling:true})
    
bot.onText(/\/start/,(msg)=>{
    bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id,'Hello World!')
})
    //I use bot command regex to prevent bot from miss understanding any user messages contain 'cls'
bot.onText(/\/cls/,(msg)=>{for (let i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
    bot.deleteMessage(msg.chat.id,msg.message_id-i).catch(er=>{return})
//if there isn't any messages to delete bot simply return
}
}
)
```

*Hopefully this might help you* :D

Refer:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage

> Note: I'm a beginner, so if there are any mistakes, please excuse me.